Why is my account frozen?
My accounts in Ether universe are frozen. I'm trying to find out why. Trust wallet is asking me to pay a third party unusual funds fee.

Thats a Scam. Trust Wallet dont sent you a payment request. Can you load the Wallet (Seed Phrase 12 Words or PrivateKey) on other Wallet? Maybe Metamask tryed?

Then this was obviously a scam. I've sent 26000 and when I transferred my ethereum to metamask, there's nothing in there.  And I can't seem the access the usdt funds which I was originally trying to withdraw when I paid a "tax free fee" to withdraw.   There is a person who was  overseeing all of this, supposedly helping me.  Obviously I was duped.   Is there anything I can do?  I've already contacted trust wallet support.   But this was occurring in Ethereum, within my trust wallet.

Red flags!  Ethereum accounts can't freeze, gas fees not "unusual,"
and Trust Wallet wouldn't ask for 3rd party fees.

Don't pay the fee!
Contact Trust Wallet support directly (official
channels only).
Consider moving your funds to a safe wallet.
More info: Trust Wallet Support: https://support.trustwallet.com/


The person who is supposedly helping me is not telling me the fee I'm required to pay is in the short term etheric universe.   Is this possible?

@Sean Absolutely! Scam alert! "Short-term etheric universe fee" is nonsense. Trust Wallet wouldn't ask for such fees. Don't pay!.
Brother, if you find my answer helpful kindly accept it.

Thank you for the advice.   I've stopped everything except keeping them in touch so I can turn in their identity.

Alright @Sean kindly accept the answer.
